# How to fix "load column of a database with double click on a td tag with jquery in a drop down menu"

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I want to load column data of a database when I dbclick on td tag in my html table.

I created two function to changed td tag to select/option tags and just want to load my current data from database that related to the td tag.

```
$(function () {
        $(".table td").dblclick(function (e) {
           e.stopPropagation();
           var currentEle = $(this);
           var value = $(this).html();
           updateVal(currentEle, value);
        });
    });

    function updateVal(currentEle, value) {
      $(currentEle).html('<select class="thVal" type="text" value="' + value + '"><?php echo "<option></option>" ?></select>');
      $(".thVal").focus();
      $(".thVal").keyup(function (event) {
          if (event.keyCode == 13) {
              $(currentEle).html($(".thVal").val().trim());
          }
      });
```

Comment: Could you formulate an anserable question? You probably only need to specify the exact problem you're having with the code. I suspect "it doesn't work", but do you get any errors (see [console](https://kb.yoast.com/kb/how-to-find-javascript-errors-with-your-browsers-console))?

Comment: there is no error on my console @KIKOSoftware

Comment: what should i write between option tag to load same data column in database and td tag? @KIKOSoftware

Comment: Sorry, I cannot answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

May be this can help if i understood your problem correctly:

replace this code this

```
'<select class="thVal" type="text" value="' + value + '"><?php echo "<option></option>" ?></select>'
```

with this

```
'<select class="thVal" type="text" name="select_name"><?php echo "<option value="' + value + '">"' + value + '"</option>" ?></select>'  //putting value from select to option so that yo cant get related option value as `td tag` and adding name attribute to get data from select
```

sorry if i am mistaken